# How to import Android Studio Project into Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

When trying to import this project into Eclipse:

https://github.com/saulmm/Android-Material-Examples

I get a lot of errors.

I've added android-support-v7 and cardview as libraries.

I'm getting these error.

```
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955): Process: com.saulmm.material, PID: 29955
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.saulmm.material/com.saulmm.material.activities.TransitionFirstActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.saulmm.material.activities.TransitionFirstActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.saulmm.material-7.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.saulmm.material-7, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2453)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:173)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.saulmm.material.activities.TransitionFirstActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.saulmm.material-7.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.saulmm.material-7, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2289)
03-22 16:14:42.828: E/AndroidRuntime(29955):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You should be aware that AS uses Gradle, Eclipse doesn't.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai what is AS sir and how do I use this with Eclipse?

Comment: Why you doing such a downgrade? Android Studio is better than Eclipse in every field.

Comment: @lusiak You guys are probably right. I haven't switched to android studio yet. I'm still used to Eclipse. When I try to start Android Studio I can't get it to run on my phone..

Comment: @losethequit Android studio can look a bit complicated but trust me its much better than eclipse in many ways, It has lots of shortcuts, features and even themes :D I recommend [this](http://www.exoguru.com/android/tools/android-studio/getting-started-with-android-studio.html) tutorial on getting started with android studio. I used to think it was over complicated when i was switching but it seems to be much more better than eclipse and once you got your way around it its quite easy :D